# SQL Server: delete all but newest "n" results

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, ssms

```
import pyodbc
    
def operations():
    # server
    server = 'DESKTOP-3KK3D6005' 
    database = 'my_database'  
    sql_driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

    # connection
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver = sql_driver, 
                            server = server, 
                            database = database, 
                            trusted_connection ='yes')

    crsr = cnxn.cursor()

    # delete oldest rows to minimize overhead.
    crsr.execute("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE timestamp IN (SELECT timestamp FROM my_table ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 10)")

    # query streamed data
    maxval = crsr.execute("SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM my_table").fetchval()
    print(maxval)
```

I only need data when it is streamed. I would like to delete everything but the nth newest rows in respect to the timestamp(epoch) to minimize overhead.

Comment: `LIMIT` isn't T-SQL Syntax;  T-SQL uses `TOP`. If, however, you want to omit the first 10 results, then you want to look at `OFFSET`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this syntax

delete oldest 10

```
delete from my_table where timestamp in (
  select top 10 timestamp from my_table t order by timestamp
);
```

delete all but 10 newest

```
delete from my_table where timestamp not in (
  select top 10 timestamp from my_table t order by timestamp desc
);
```

or, we can find the min timestamp from top N
and delete the rest

```
delete from my_table where timestamp < (
select min(timestamp) from 
 (select top 10 timestamp from my_table order by timestamp desc) m
);
```